# If you need no casting, and you need to check the most specific (runtime) type of an object, which is faster? .GetType() & typeof(), or is operator?

Tags: c#, casting, typeof, gettype

1) `.GetType()` will return the runtime type of the object on which it is called,
which is the most specific type in the inheritance hierarchy. You can use the `typeof()`
function to get a `Type` for a classname 
2) The is operator will check whether the type of the left hand side object
is a subtype of, or the same type as the type specified on the right hand side
3) Given that you only need to check the most specific type of an object, and you need no casting, is the former (1) considerably faster than the latter (2)?
4) Does the `is` operator actually perform casting and checks for null, or
this behaviour have been modified in a later version of C Sharp?

Comment: There are many situations where the two are not equivalent. For example, if `T` is not a sealed type `x.GetType() == typeof(T)` means that the precise run-time type of `x` is exactly `T`, while `x is T` means that the type of `x` is either `T` or something that derives from or implements `T`, or something that otherwise allows a reference conversion to `T`. Even for sealed types the two may be different because of co- and contravariant generic parameters. For example, let `Func<string> f = () => "a";`. Then `f is Func<object>` is true because of the covariance of `Func<out TResult>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First 4) as it's simpler. The `is` operator is implemented with the `as` operator.

```
x is C
```

is the same as

```
x as C != null
```

For the source you can look at [the fabulous Eric Lippert's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/16/is-is-as-or-is-as-is/). Currently (commit e09c42a), the Roslyn compiler translates both to

```
isinst C
ldnull
cgt.un
```

Where `isinst` is the magic instruction that tries to cast `x` to `C` and leaves the casted reference on top of the stack, or `null` if it fails. The remaining two instructions are the check for `null`.

As for performance, it's hard to say definitely. In theory, checking with `is` should be faster, as it's a built-in CLR instruction that's heavily optimized for what it does, while the other check has to call three methods, the `GetType()`, `GetTypeFromHandle(RuntimeTypeHandle)` and the equality on `Type`. There's also the standard check-for-null-and-throw-NRE involved with calling the `GetType()`. A very crude benchmark supports this hypothesis: [link to DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XtJbMS). If someone is willing to perform a more sophisticated benchmark, go ahead.

Obviously I can imagine you could have an inheritance hierarchy so deep and complicated the `is` check will take longer than any overhead of `GetType()` ever could. Feel free to subtype my benchmark up to C100 and check if that's enough :)

EDIT:
I think I should add that this discussion is purely theoretical. In production code you should use `x is C`, as it's concise and more robust since it checks the entire hierarchy for subtyping. If you have a hot path that checks a given instance's type and you know for a fact that the hierarchy is flat, you probably should redesign the system to avoid that check instead of uglifying the code to squeeze out some performance.

Comment: You dig deep, but you are right. Except GetType() is not virtual, and all type-objects are Singletons, so to compare them is just a compare of references. A "builtin" Function has no meaning on performance actually, cause the IL to Native compilation does some more optimization again. IL has no idea of "i++"  but the JIT-Compile might use the INC instruction despite of that. So the better argument for the "is" is. It's shorter code, easier to read.

Comment: @Holger You're right, I goofed with the virtual. The argument for shorter code is obvious, after all `is` was introduced as syntactic sugar for this kinds of things, and also it checks sub-types up in the inheritance hierarchy, not only concrete types. And you're also right that the jitter could just as well recognise the "`GetType == typeof`" pattern and optimize it. My guess would be that it could, but it doesn't, and thus a lookup in a CLR-internal structure is faster than actually instantiating `Type` objects and comparing them.

Answer (score 3):

`typeof(x)` is to get a Type-Object of a type Literal, like `typeof(int)`. It's a runtime constant.

For `object.GetType()` you need an object instance.

```
 if (x is IList)
```

The is operator does a casting, but returns bool on success, or false, if x is null or an incompatible type.
With

```
 if (x is IList list)
```

You can do the boolean test and the casting at the same time.

It does not make sense, to talk about performance, cause that are completly different operations.

if you want to get the type of an object instance `object.GetType()` is your only option, but you can test it agains a type literal like

```
 x.GetType() == typeof(List)
```

While you can be sure

```
 x.GetType() == typeof(IList)
```

will always be false, since GetType will never return the type of an interface.
For this test you would need

```
typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType());
```

Comment: I wanted to know whether (5.GetType() == typeof(int)) is faster than (5 is Int32). If you test against a most specific, concrete type then they essentially do the same thing. Like if concrete classes B and C inherit from A, and you want to know whether a variable of type A has the most specific type B, then you can use both (aInstance is B) and (aInstance.GetType() == typeof(B))

Comment: But you now how to test this yourself, don't you ? you measure time with a stopwatch, or a performance profiler. It can vary from machine to machine.
The two functions do NOT the same.if you have a class D derived from B, than `instance is B` will return true, on both D and B. You should not do any coding, relying on a certain class hiearchie. Unless you declare B as sealed  - in this case you two snippets might really be equivalent.

Comment: yeah I was aware they do not do the same. That is why I described what they do in the question. "is" operator is also suited for checking whether the object is a subtype of the type on the RHS. And I wrote you can check teh actualy type of the object. But in this case you can use whichever you choose.

Comment: It's not a good idea, to write code, that works only, "in this case". You have to ensure your assumptions with assertions and so on, and all just to gain 10 Nanoseconds. You can measure it only if you have a million iterations over this line of code, and then there might be much more lines, easier to optimize for performance.